# How to create response POJO from XML SOAP schema

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I have been given this task that I should create request and response class of an API. And the API works with XML SOAP. I don't have problem sending request via SOAP but I cant find a way to create a response POJO. Google search didn`t help much with what I wanted.

Below is a sample XML response that I get from API. What I want to know that first, how to generate below xml's java class and then how to unmarshall this XML to create an object of that class?

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://TekTravel/HotelBookingApi/IHotelService/HotelSearchResponse</a:Action>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <HotelSearchResponse xmlns="http://TekTravel/HotelBookingApi">
        <Status>
            <StatusCode>01</StatusCode>
            <Description>Successful: HotelSearch Successful</Description>
        </Status>
        <ResponseTime>31/05/2018 07:15:50</ResponseTime>
        <SessionId>String</SessionId>
        <NoOfRoomsRequested>1</NoOfRoomsRequested>
        <CityId>122727</CityId>
        <CheckInDate>31/07/2018 00:00:00</CheckInDate>
        <CheckOutDate>31/08/2018 00:00:00</CheckOutDate>
        <RoomGuests>
            <RoomGuest AdultCount="2" ChildCount="0" />
        </RoomGuests>
        <HotelResultList>
            <HotelResult>
                <ResultIndex>1</ResultIndex>
                <HotelInfo>
                    <HotelCode>1223616</HotelCode>
                    <HotelName>Holiday Inn Istanbul Airport</HotelName>
                    <HotelPicture>http://api.tbotechnology.in/imageresource.aspx?img=9eMP+0FIICgCIk6ZClzZH9Cs+1gwAq6BFWcc22yNLMF/UJIXMdxPdU6RmZuwTZuiHZTzqW9k4hFjD8j5qsCZ6ux+KKuGpw2ckqGcenpT20gdryjECrrh0A==</HotelPicture>
                    <HotelDescription>Property Location With a stay at Holiday Inn Istanbul Airport Hotel in Istanbul (Bagcilar), you&amp;apos;ll be close to Mall of Istanbul and Ataturk Olympic Stadium </HotelDescription>
                    <Latitude>41.05856</Latitude>
                    <Longitude>28.81395</Longitude>
                    <HotelAddress>Mahmutbey Mahallesi Tasocagi Yolu Caddesi 35 </HotelAddress>
                    <Rating>FiveStar</Rating>
                    <HotelPromotion />
                    <TripAdvisorRating>3.5</TripAdvisorRating>
                    <TripAdvisorReviewURL>http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g293974-d860088-Reviews-m19454-Holiday_Inn_Istanbul_Airport_</TripAdvisorReviewURL>
                    <TagIds>126</TagIds>
                </HotelInfo>
                <MinHotelPrice TotalPrice="3515.40" Currency="USD" B2CRates="false" OriginalPrice="3515.40" />
                <IsPkgProperty>false</IsPkgProperty>
                <IsPackageRate>false</IsPackageRate>
                <MappedHotel>true</MappedHotel>
            </HotelResult>
        </HotelResultList>
    </HotelSearchResponse>
</s:Body>
```

Comment: POJO are usually created from WSDL, not from sample SOAPMessage, post your WSDL.

Comment: You need the WSDL file and then generate stub or skeleton java classes with the help of APACHE CXF or AXIS 2(https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html)

Comment: Google to the rescue: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/